# Iterating through Algolia hits overwrites each ID with ID of last result

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an Algolia index with data like this:

```
id:FirstLastNumber
name:First Name
objectID:FirstLastNumber
address:1234 Fake Street
city:New York
state:NY
```

I query and dump the results onto a page like this:

```
algoliaIndex.search({
        query: input
    }, function searchDone(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        for (var hit in content.hits) {
            var resultName = content.hits[hit].name;
            var resultCity = content.hits[hit].city;
            var resultID = content.hits[hit].id
            var resultItem = document.createElement('a');
            resultItem.className = "collection-item";
            resultItem.innerHTML = "<div class='list-text'><span 
                class='title-in-list'>" + resultName + "</span><br><span 
                class='date-in-list'>" + resultCity + "</span></div>";
            resultItem.onclick = function() {
                //pull details for the member.
                getMember(resultID);
            };
            results.appendChild(resultItem);
        };
    });
```

95% of this works exactly as intended. However, for the `onclick` function, it puts the last result's ID in every single `resultItem`. So when I click on any result, it pulls the details for the last member in the results list. For example, if I had 3 results, no matter what result I click, the last result's ID is passed to the `getMember()`. This happens regardless of whether I use the id key or the objectID key. What am I doing wrong here?

I use this same code to pull data from Firebase into a different, albeit identially written, list of members, and it works just fine. I can get the Algolia portion to work if I do this:

```
resultItem.id = resultID;
resultItem.onclick = function(event) {
    getMember(event.srcElement.id);
};
```

How can I get the id or objectID returned from Algolia to stick to the respective item?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to how javascript scoping works. Even though it appears as though you are creating a function with a distinct `resultId` on each key iteration, it's actually not the case. Since the `resultId` is determined by the external `hit` variable, and since `hit` is overwritten during every loop, you end up having multiple references to the same `hit` variable, hence why you always see a return value for the last ID that `hit` is set to in the loop.

One solution is to wrap your onClick function declaration in a function, so that it creates a closure over the distinct `hit` value at each iteration. Perhaps this will work:

```
    setHandler = function(id) {
            return function() {getMember(id)};
        };

    resultItem.onClick = setHandler(resultID)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope problem. In your loop, the hit variable is global in scope. You can either wrap the code inside of the for loop in a closure that captures the value of `hit` at that point in the loop or you can use `let` instead of var if you are ok with using ES6 features.

### Option 1

:

```
for (var hit in content.hits) {
  (function(){
    //the code you had inside the for loop
  })(hit);
}
```

### Option 2

```
for (let hit in content.hits)
```

Comment: Thank you both! I understand this a little better now.